# How to tag text based on its category using OpenNLP?

Tags: machine-learning, nlp, stanford-nlp, opennlp, text-classification

I want to tag text based on the category it belongs to ...

For example ...

"Clutch and gear is monitored using microchip " -> clutch /mechanical , gear/mechanical , microchip / electronic

"software used here to monitor hydrogen levels" -> software/computer , hydrogen / chemistry ..

How to do this using openNLP or other NLP engines.

**MY WORKS** 
I tried NER model , but It needs large number of training corpus which I don't have ?

**My Need**

Do any ready made training corpus available for NER or  classification (it must contains scientific and engineering words).. ?

Comment: Could you be more specific with your question? Do you know your categories ahead of time? What are you using the categories for? Do you need to do named entity recognition as well, or just pos tagging? What have you tried thus far?

Comment: @SlaterTyranus      I need name entity recognition ... I tried with my own text index... but I can't build on my own because the words are so large in number..

Comment: I want categories such as scientific words , engineering words , technical words .. like that

Answer (score 1):

If you want to create a set of class labels for an entire sentence, then you will want to use the Doccat lib. With Doccat you would get a prob distribution for each chunk of text.
with doccat your sample would produce something like this:

"Clutch and gear is monitored using microchip " -> mechanical 0.85847568,  electronic 0.374658

with doocat you will lose the keyword->classlabel mapping, so if you really need it doccat might not cut it.

as for NER, OpenNLP has an addon called Modelbuilder-addon that may help you. It is designed to expedite the creation of NER model building. You can create a file/list of as many of the terms for each category as you can think of, then create a file of a bunch of sentences, then use the addon to create an NER model using the seed terms and the file of sentences. see this post where I described it before with code example. You will have to pull down the addon from SVN.

[OpenNLP: foreign names does not get recognized](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20509678/opennlp-foreign-names-does-not-get-recognized/21323571#21323571)

Comment: Thanks.. @markg  Can you provide the link for that doccat lib.. (google can't find).... Is there any online text corpus that have categories mapping that you mentioned above ...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21533837/how-to-implement-category-based-text-tagging-using-wordnet-or-related-to-wordnet

Comment: here is a link to another post where I show how to use the doccat opennlp lib. you will need the opennlp jars 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21091224/nlp-to-classify-label-the-content-of-a-sentence-ruby-binding-necesarry/21120269#21120269